# ArcGIS Tool to Delete only Geodatabase content (feature classes, tables, etc)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, enterprise-geodatabase, data-management

Situation:

Need to add a **Tool** to my ModelBuider to **Delete** only the content from an Enterprise (SDE) Geodatabase (containing features classes, tables, relationship classes).

Tool "Delete" (from Toolbox "Data Management") deletes the Geodatabase and only want to delete its content.

Any help?

Comment: Look at the Truncate Table tool under Table in Data Management.

Comment: I am not sure if this will accomplish the goal, I believe the truncate tool has to be run on individual tables, and will not truncate all objects in a work space.

Comment: Truncate is the most efficient way to remove features from an enterpise table (orders of magnitude faster than Delete).  It would be need to be run on each object, in the appropriate order to avoid referential constraints.

Comment: The question is not about truncating tables to preserve table structure, it is about deleting database objects entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you create a series of models using [iterators](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Iterator_toolset/00400000000n000000/). You can create a model for each type and nest the models as sub models in order to include all of them into a single model. You would have to do this because a model can have only one iterator. So each model will iterate through the data object then deltete. Use preconditions to control the flow. That should work perfectly for what you are trying to acomplish.

And example of what I mean below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

IF you R-click the "Truncate Table", you have an option to do batch. This will allow you to add as many tables that you would need to perform this tool for.

Comment: While this would work to remove all records from each feature class or table, the question is asking how to remove the actual feature classes and tables, not just the records.